# How to automate SSL certificate monitoring renewal process in Apache Tomcat and IBM WebSphere server?

Tags: ssl-certificate, tomcat, websphere

We have bunch of Apache Tomcat and IBM Websphere application servers and in the process of adding ton of new servers for new projects. Wondering if there are any commercial or open source tools that can monitor and automate the process of SSL certificates for internal and external/outbound HTTPS connections. I would like to know if any of these steps can be automated, specially when dealing with 50-100+ server and JVM instances.

I believe this issue a common issue for many large enterprises, so will be interesting to know how this issue is dealt with in Java and non-Java environments in traditional server and Docker container environments.

Comment: Try looking at **Venafy**

Comment: @SergeyNudnov,, good information, briefly looked at Venafi site, will try to research if the solutions would match what we are looking for.